# SlickGrid- How can I pass parameters into a formatter, from the columns loop (including long detailed answer)

Tags: jquery, json, slickgrid

I have a given grid. 
I want to place in each row, inside an attribute, an id value. (in order to get the row identity, to perform delete & edit actions).

The best way I thought about is to print it into an attrubute, using a formatter, but I cannot find the way to pass the id to the formatter function, cause the formatter call is columns deceleration level, and I'm getting each row id, inside the *data* loop.

How to do that?

```
function NameFormatter(row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext) {
    return '<span data-user-id="'+id+'">"'+text+'"</span>';
}

columns.push({ 
   id: "name", name: "Name", field: "name", width: 180, 
   cssClass: "cellName", sortable: true, formatter:NameFormatter
})

for (var i = 0; i < list_users.length; i++) {
    data[i] = {
        /*
           What I do here?
           How do I pass list_users[i].id & 
           list_users[i].name to the formatter from here? 
        */
        name: list_users[i].name,
        role: returnRole(list_users[i].role),
        email: list_users[i].email,
        portfolios: 'no attr for now'
    };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The formatter is called at render time. So all your data is already loaded in the grid.

Why not use an exclusive column for the ID (you could exclude it from showing after render by calling grid.setColumns)? Or better yet, use the dataView - it already has a **mandatory** column for ID - which you can use for editing/deleting.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi @Ganeshk. >> Regarding grid.setColumns- how can I reprint the DOM without showing the user the ID column, which I whish to hide it from him? >> Regarding DataView- Can you expand a little more on it? Thank you for your great help!

Comment: grid.setColumns - lets say you had columns {id, a, b, c} set while declaring the grid; after the grid is initialized, you can call the grid.setColumns(newColumns) - where newColumns is the new column array which excludes id.
DataView - this on the other hand is better suited to your needs I think. Check SlickGrid's example 4 [link](http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example4-model.html). The data object passed to the dataView should always have a unique ID, which is the first column forced by the dataView syntax, and which you can use for your purposes as needed.

Answer (score 6):

Documenting here the code and answer, for future use by any user which will stumble upon my question.

The logic of SlickGrid works like this:

1. **Columns** that define the table headers and other run time properties like Sortable, width, etc.
2. **Data loop** that gets your json & register values to the *DataView*, which hold for us memnbers.
3. this **members** than become useful when we use **formatters**.

When you call a formatter, inside the *Columns* declaration, you just need to call the formatter. Slick grid will do the rest.

This is my column definition, where I have a {span} element with value and id, based on conditions.

```
columns.push({ 
    id: "options", 
    name: "Options", 
    field: "options", 
    width: 110, 
    cssClass: "cellOptions slick-last-cell", 
    formatter: optionsFormatter 
})
```

If everything been defined right, the ***Formatter*** will pass all the params needed for conditions or any other type of job.

The formatter receives from dataView all the Row Params been passed by you/us. If I have defined my Data like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < list_users.length; i++) {
    data[i] = {
        id: list_users[i].id,
        name: list_users[i].name,
        role: returnRole(list_users[i].role),
        email: list_users[i].email,
        portfolios: 'no attr for now',
        isPending: list_users[i].isPending
    };
}
```

than my dataContext will hold this array in his hands, and will pass it to me to the formatter, where there I will do what ever I want with the variables values.

```
 function optionsFormatter(row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext) {
    if (dataContext.isPending) {
        return '<span onclick="deleteUser(' + dataContext.id + ')" class="actionIcon delete">Cancel</span>';
    } else {
        return '<span onclick="editUser(' + dataContext.id + ')" class="actionIcon edit">Edit</span>';
    }
}
```

As you can see, id & isPending are not visible in the grid to the user, but they are available for any dataContext.

That's it. Very simple the moment you're getting it.

Answer (score 0):

I push a commit in my slickgrid fork, to add a new parameter metadata to method formatter, which allow pass column metadata and use metadata in formatter method.

https://github.com/Francks11/X-SlickGrid/commit/b2e14e6cb169de6059757434e7db458a997320b3

```
    function DoubleFormatter(row, cell, value, columnDef, dataContext, metadata) {

    var formattedValue = parseFloat( value ).toFixed(3);

    return isNaN( formattedValue ) ? "" : formattedValue;
}
```